# Trouble calling SQL Server stored procedure within Java

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures

Below is a generic class I wrote that calls a stored procedure on the server:

```
public class StoredProc {

Connection con = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
CallableStatement cs = null;

public StoredProc(String jdbcResource, String storedProcName){

    this(jdbcResource, storedProcName, new String[0], new String[0]);
}

public StoredProc(String jdbcResource, String storedProcName, String[] params,String[]        paramTypes){

    Connection con = new databaseConnection(jdbcResource).getConnection();

    //Get length of parameters and sets stored procs params (?, ?, ...etc)
    String procParams = "";
    int paramSize = params.length;
    if(paramSize != 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < paramSize; i++){
            if(i == paramSize){
                procParams += "?";
            }else{
                procParams += "?, ";
            }
        }
    }

    try{           

        CallableStatement cs = this.con.prepareCall("{?=call "+storedProcName+"  ("+procParams+")}");

        for(int j = 0; j < params.length; j++){
            if (paramTypes[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Int")) {
                int x = 0;
                try{
                    x = Integer.parseInt(params[j]);
                } catch(Exception e) {}
                cs.setInt(j, x);
            } else if (paramTypes[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Boolean")) {
                boolean x = false;
                try{
                    x = (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("True")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("T")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("1")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) || (params[j].equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));
                } catch(Exception e) {}
                cs.setBoolean(j, x);
            } else if (paramTypes[j].equalsIgnoreCase("String")) {
                cs.setString(j, params[j]);
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Problem constructing callableStatement: "+e);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    }

}

public ResultSet runQuery(){

    try{
        rs = cs.executeQuery();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Problem executing stored procedure: "+e);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    }
    return rs;

}

public void runUpdate(){

    try{
        cs.executeUpdate();
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Problem executing stored procedure: "+e);
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
    }
}

} //end of class
```

for some reason I'm getting a NullPointerException on the line I'm trying to construct a CallableStatement --> CallableStatement cs = this.con.prepareCall("{?=call "+storedProcName+"  ("+procParams+")}");

The callable statement should look like this at run time:

```
cs = this.con.prepareCall({?=call getUnlinkedDirectdeposits()});
```

The stored proc is called this in the database: [dbo].[getUnlinkedDirectdeposits]

Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong "`con`" variable. In your method you're initialising a variable (local to the method) called `con`:

```
Connection con = new databaseConnection(jdbcResource).getConnection();
```

But then you use `this.con`, which is the `con` field of the `StoredProc` object you're currently executing in. Since it was never initialised, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Connection` field is null!

You create a new `Connection` instance in `StoredProc` instead of assigning it to the field `con` of your class. But when trying to created the `CallableStatement` your are using the `this.con` which has not been set before.